# How to commit image using InputConnection Class?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am working on InputConnection Class of android. To commit text, we generally use below method:

```
ic.commitText("Some Value", 1);
```

But i want to commit an Image in place of Text. It may be something like this:

```
ic.commitImage("/drawable/Image", 1);
```

But this type of method doesn't exist?. Any idea how to use some alternative?

Comment: were you able to do this ????

Comment: Nope..i close that issue..No solution yet